# How can the orbit of Jupiter's moons be used to calculate the speed of light?

Tags: speed-of-light, measurements, jupiter

How can the orbit of Jupiter's moons be used to calculate the speed of light? It seems this was one of the first methods and goes back to 1656.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18472/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From  [Roemer and Light Speed](http://www.amnh.org/education/resources/rfl/web/essaybooks/cosmic/p_roemer.html):

> The orbital period of Io is now known to be 1.769 Earth days. The satellite is eclipsed by Jupiter once every orbit, as seen from the Earth. By timing these eclipses over many years, Roemer noticed something peculiar. The time interval between successive eclipses became steadily shorter as the Earth in its orbit moved toward Jupiter and became steadily longer as the Earth moved away from Jupiter. These differences accumulated. From his data, Roemer estimated that when the Earth was nearest to Jupiter (at E1), eclipses of Io would occur about eleven minutes earlier than predicted based on the average orbital period over many years. And 6.5 months later, when the Earth was farthest from Jupiter (at E2), the eclipses would occur about eleven minutes later than predicted.
>
> Roemer knew that the true orbital period of Io could have nothing to do with the relative positions of the Earth and Jupiter. In a brilliant insight, he realized that the time difference must be due to the finite speed of light. That is, light from the Jupiter system has to travel farther to reach the Earth when the two planets are on opposite sides of the Sun than when they are closer together. Romer estimated that light required twenty-two minutes to cross the diameter of the Earth’s orbit. The speed of light could then be found by dividing the diameter of the Earth’s orbit by the time difference.

Comment: I can see how the calculation of dividing that large distance by the time difference could lead to a large speed, but I'm not clear on why an event like a moon orbiting a planet, would be measurably different in duration based on how far away it is from us? Can you help me with this misunderstanding?

Comment: It doesn't matter how far away the object is from us, what matters is that as the Earth orbits the sun, Jupiter's distance to Earth changes by about 2 Astronomical Units (16 light minutes).  It's the variation in distance between Earth and Jupiter that makes the measurement possible, because the moons orbiting Jupiter are precise almost like clockwork, so, when the Earth is far from Jupiter and the earth near to Jupiter, we can see the clock doesn't keep precise time, and that error in precision is explained by the changing distance between Earth and Jupiter.

Comment: I understand that there is a discrepancy. I am still trying to understand why.

Comment: Shouldn't the movement of the Earth, instead of its position, be the important factor? In other words, when we move towards Jupiter the eclipses should appear closer (in time) to each other, and farther when we move away from Jupiter, in a sort of Doppler effect; the distance shouldn't matter. But that isn't what the quote is saying.

Comment: @Javier: No.  We are not looking at the time between eclipses, we are looking at the absolute time of each eclipse.  If the distance from Earth to Jupiter did not change the times would be a nice arithmetic progression.  The motion of Earth imposes a sine wave on the time with amplitude the light time over the diameter of the Earth's orbit around the sun (assuming Jupiter's orbit is circular).  We asses the effect and find the light travel time over the diameter of Earth's orbit.

Comment: Think of the moons as hands on a clock.  We can read that clock and compare it to our clocks and see how our clock changes relative to that clock.

Comment: @Javier There is *also* a relativistic effect like what you mention, but it is negligible here since Earth only orbits at 0.0001c.